# Cpanel overwrites amazon SES entries in exim.conf

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpanel, amazon-ses

I need to add some additional configurations on my exim.conf file. But it will get overwrited after some time automatically. I read in some other forum to add entries via exim configuration editor in cpanel. But, on that editor, i cant add such entries. It only allows to select a field and its value only. How can i add custom entries?

```
begin authenticators

ses_login:
driver = plaintext
public_name = LOGIN
client_send = : 
===========
begin routers

send_via_ses:
driver = manualroute
domains = ! +local_domains
transport = ses_smtp
route_list = * email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
========
begin transports

#entry for amazon
ses_smtp:
driver = smtp
port = 25
hosts_require_auth = $host_address
hosts_require_tls = $host_address
```

Entry is something like the above entry. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Exim Advanced config edit, you can add them.

For the auth, search for the bold text "Section: AUTH" -- there is a text area below it... enter in the "ses_login" details.

For the routers, search for the bold text "Section: PREROUTERS" -- there is a text area below it... enter in the "send_via_ses" details.

Lastly, for the transports, search for the bold text "Section: TRANSPORTSTART" -- there is a text area below it... enter in the "ses_smtp" details.

Once you are finished, scroll all the way down and save your config.. It should now be maintained in your /etc/exim.conf.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to /etc/exim.conf.local which is the customization file for Cpanel. You will find all sections described by half crazed. 
In fact, the Advanced configuration page for exim stores all the custom data in exim.conf.local
Since the file is super small, it helps to quickly implement changes and test.